# Number of Cores v. Processor Speed

Tags: lubuntu, cpu

The short question: is Ubuntu/Lubuntu designed to run/utilize multi  (2+) core CPUs or is CPU speed the better approach for running these distros?

I am designing a new PC and specing the CPU. I have read that some current software is not designed to take advantage of multicore processors. I began to wonder if this may apply to the OS also. Lubuntu/Ubuntu is my OS of choice for this new box. From a speed aspect, I am leaning towards Lubuntu as it is less "intensive".

Now, the bigger question: I am **not** a gamer. I surf the web, having 3-6 webpages open at once. I also may have Open Office running and frequently download .PDF files and may open them. Thunderbird will be running, pinging every minute. I stream music during all this other activity.

Should I focus on the fastest processor speed I can afford or look to a processor with the most cores?

.

Comment: Pentium would just do... but this question is not related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, Ubuntu can use multiple cores, and it does it pretty well. In fact, most supercomputers run Linux, and they have tons of processors.

Even though this is true, it also depends upon the software to make appropriate use of multiple cores. Not all software can do multi threading, in this case, such software would use only one core.

To answer your question, most of the software you will use are not CPU intensive, so they would either not support multi threading or they will never use it. Hence you are better off using faster processor than one with multiple cores. Still, you might want at least dual core, just in case you need it.